# How to pass a javascript variable to php using getJSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I'm trying to create a page that lists some notifications according to the user id.

I have this Javascript function to get the results as JSON

```
  var url="http://localhost/app/demo/getNotifications.php";
    $$.getJSON(url, function (result) {
      $$.each(result, function (i, field) {

        var nID = field.id;
        var nDonor = field.donor_id;

        // APPENDS DATA TO LISTFVIEW
        $$("#notlistview").append("HTML HERE");
      });

    });
```

And this is the php file:

```
<?php
include "db1.php";

$USERID = " ";

$data=array();
$q=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM blood_donations WHERE requester_id='USERID'  ORDER BY `id` DESC");
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
 $data[]=$row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

My question is how do I pass a value from javascript to fill in the $USERID in the php file with the sent Value?

I only need to retrieve the results related to the USERID, so if you have another way, that's fine too.

Comment: your code is **vulnerable** to sql injection attacks;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the builtin global `$_GET` to retrieve parameters:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['userid'])) {
    $USERID = $_GET['userid'];
} else {
    $USERID = " ";
}
?>
```

And to pass the value from jQuery:

```
$.getJSON(url,
{
    userid: myUserID 
},
function (result) {
        // your result function
});
```

Comment: Thank you! let me give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Change this...

```
$$.getJSON(url, function (result) {
```

To this...

```
$$.getJSON(url, {userID:123}, function (result) {
```

Set 123 to whatever value you want.

Then in your PHP get your variable from $_GET['userID']

Be careful. Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, same as first answer which I already tried! But I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.

Comment: No problem. I'm new to stack overflow. I find it frustrating when I have taken time to answer a question and half way though, writing the answer, someone else comes in with the same answer before me and steals my thunder! Ah well!

Comment: Haha, yeah it happened to me before! this is how it is, first correct answer and you're obligated to mark it as complete, lol. Thanks and sorry again.